# How to implement a text file into a linked list?

Tags: c, compression, huffman-code

What I'm trying to do is a Huffman algorithm. One of the specifications of the program is that the user will create a .txt file that contains the characters with their corresponding frequencies. So it'd be like a list of characters and beside each is the weight of that character. Below will be an example of that.txt file:

H5
J4
K6
S9
L2
N1

What I've managed to do is to read and display the .txt file. And I'm having a hard time to implement it into a linked list. I've tried reading the fread() fwrite() and all those other functions, but I really can't get the gist of it. Any kind of help is very much appreciated. :D

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, but isn't what you need for Huffmann coding a _tree_, rather than a linked list?

Comment: Yup, but before I make it into a tree, I must point the characters into their corresponding frequencies and a linked list is pretty much the best way to go.

Comment: Hardly, how many character are there, can this expand? No you have the 26 characters and you have to access them frequently so an Array of structures is way better.

Answer (score 0):

Despite of the fact that you're going to need a tree, I assume you're using a `struct` for storage, something like

```c
struct list {
    char *symbol;
    int prob;
    struct list *next;
};
```

So if you've managed to read your file then you're having strings, "H5", "J4", and so on. All you've got to do is splitting the string for instance with [strtok](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html) or a similar function. Now you can copy the symbol to `*symbol` and convert the probability with [atoi](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/atoi.html) to an `int` and thus writing it to `prob`.

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, that you should think about the structure of your file, becaus "H5" is probably not that good parseable with `strtok` ond the other hand maybe you don't need `strtok` at all, if the first character is always the symbol and afterwards are only counts.

**Edit #2:** Also give [fscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html) a try (much easier than `strtok` if you know the format).

Comment: About the suitability of `int`: The data we read are not probabilities, but raw character counts. `int` is alright for that, and it is also what is needed for the actual tree, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a tree, an array of structures is all you need. He should count the occurences of characers and there just can be 26 +/- (for other countries) characters (assuming numbers are not "wanted".
So the idea with the struct is goog. but one could imagine either an Array of longs or an Array of structs as proposed.

Anyway if we define array[0] = frequencies_of_As we can calculate the occurences of the characters very easy.

```
char *asUpper = toupper(ch);
frequency_Array [char - 'A'] += 1;
```

and writing would just be a simple loop

```
up_to = 'Z' - 'A';
for (i = 0, ch = 'A'; i < up_to; i++, ch++){
   fprintf(file, "%d%c", i, ch)
```

or the like

If you wan to read the file and this file is that strict a simple loop should be sufficient also, I assume we just have the 26 letters of the alphabet

```
 long counter; char ch;
    for i = 0; i < up_to; i++){
          int how_many = fscanf(file_to_use, "%c%d\n", &counter, &ch);
          assert(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z');
          frequenceArray[ch - 'A'] = counter;
     }
```

Comment: This sounds like a procedure to create the .txt file the OP was talking about. But wasn't the question about _reading_ that file and doing something with the information in it?